# Is it possible to edit a Wordpress page in HTML?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to add something in HTML to my homepage in Wordpress. Is there anyway that I can do this? I've made the changes via inspect an element and I am happy with how it looks. I know how to change the HTML on things like the header (as the files are stored under names such as header.php) but I don't think it's possible to do to home pages as the data is just stored in databases. Can anyone offer a solution around this?

The homepage is static and composed with Visual Composer.

Thanks in advance.

Write a comment if you need anymore information.

Comment: You can either add HTML within the post content or edit the template itself if your WordPress instance allows that. Either solution depends on your theme, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create page template and then assign see below image or [read here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) too 
  [image]